# Combinations in python using itertools

Tags: python, math, combinations

Hello there is there a way to do 5C2 in python? I am a noob in python and i can't find the answer anywhere. The answer has to be 10. Ive been trying to play around with but i can only get errors, Here's my code I need to get 10

```
from itertools import *
    print(combinations(5,2))
```

It gives me:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try scipy and "binomial coefficient".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [35]: def choose(n,k):
   ....:     return math.factorial(n)/(math.factorial(k)*math.factorial(n-k))
   ....: 

In [36]: choose(5,3)
Out[36]: 10.0
```

Don't forget to import math

Comment: But 5C3 on calculator gives you 10 not 40

Comment: Perhaps you should change that floating-point division to an integer division, to get the integer value the OP seems to expect.

Comment: Apart from the fact that it's wrong and `choose(5,3)` should return `10` instead of `40`, this answer ignores the title, stating *...using itertools*

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: OP wasn't looking for a solution that used itertools. OP's attempt at a solution used itertools. I simply read between the lines a little to realize exactly what OP was looking for

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest sorry if the title was misleading i do not mind what method i use

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to find number of combinations (n choose k) as one number, in my opinion, the following is the simplest way, if you can use Python 3.8.
From Python 3.8 there is the `math.comb(n, k)` function in math module.

```py
import math

print(math.comb(5,2))
```

Gives

```
10
```

Some references:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_math_comb.asp
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-math-comb-method/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking explicitely about finding the number of combinations **using itertools**, the solution would be

```
import itertools
print len(list(itertools.combinations(range(5),2)))
```

Let me explain: `itertools.combinations(iterator, k)` takes as arguments an iterator (which can be a list) and the number of elements to chose from that list. Instead of answering the question of how many combinations of `k` element tuples you can draw from that list, it returns that list directly. 
So given an `n` element list from which all `k`-tuples should be drawn and looking at the length of that list, gives you the binomial coefficient.

Of course there are easier ways to calculate the binomial coefficient, using e.g. `scipy.special.binom`

```
import scipy
print scipy.special.binom(5,2)
```

Comment: Please adapt this to python3 @ImportanceOfBeginErnest (the edit queue is full and python 2 is sunset)